# How is it possible that filesystem method much more slower then Win32?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to iterate recursive by given path and get all the possible paths to files. In order to do this I went with `filesystem` solution

```
std::vector<std::string> get_all_files_recursive(const fs::path& path)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    for (const auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
    {
        if (!fs::is_directory(p))
        {
            fs::path path = p.path();
            result.push_back(path.u8string());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

But then when I tried to run this method on the dir which contains 25k files I noticed that it takes me a lot of time ~17893ms.

Then I tried to use Win32 solution

```
bool ListFiles(std::wstring path, std::wstring mask, std::vector<std::wstring>& files) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW ffd;
    std::wstring spec;
    std::stack<std::wstring> directories;

    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();

    while (!directories.empty()) {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFileW(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            return false;
        }

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 &&
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And was prity surprised when I saw that process time took me just ~603ms.

There is my code example:

```
// PlaygroundCPP.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <filesystem>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using recursive_directory_iterator = std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

std::vector<std::string> get_all_files_recursive(const fs::path& path)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    for (const auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
    {
        if (!fs::is_directory(p))
        {
            fs::path path = p.path();
            result.push_back(path.u8string());
        }
    }

    return result;
}

bool ListFiles(std::wstring path, std::wstring mask, std::vector<std::wstring>& files) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW ffd;
    std::wstring spec;
    std::stack<std::wstring> directories;

    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();

    while (!directories.empty()) {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFileW(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            return false;
        }

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 &&
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string path_to_dir = "path_to_your_dir_with_25k_files"; 

    //*** WAY 1
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::string> all_paths = get_all_files_recursive(path_to_dir);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double dtMS = static_cast<double>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()) / 1000.0;
    printf("HERE EXECUTION TIME WAY 1 IN MS: %f, size of buff :: %d\n", dtMS, (int)all_paths.size());
    //*** END OF WAY 1

    //*** WAY 2
    auto t11 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(path_to_dir);
    std::vector<std::wstring> files;
    ListFiles(wide, L"*", files);

    auto t22 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double dtMS1 = static_cast<double>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t22 - t11).count()) / 1000.0;
    printf("HERE EXECUTION TIME WAY 2 IN MS: %f, size of buff :: %d\n", dtMS1, (int)files.size());
    //*** END OF WAY 2


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

So, the question is - how is it possible that there is so significant a difference in execution time?

**EDIT**

Fliped the order of methods 2 -> 1

[image]

Comment: Disk cache can have a big impact. Did you run both solutions with a cold cache? Or simply reverse the order in which the two are being run?

Comment: Do you realise that you copy/convert path of the filenames several times? While in Win32 way you store output in the native format with no conversions at all?

Comment: @Thomas I am not sure about `cold cache`, but what am I doing is just run at the same `main()` firstly one method and then second one synchronously. So, they two went over the same files, but with very different performance.

Comment: @ALX23z hm, actually no. Do you mean here `fs::path path = p.path();` and here `result.push_back(path.u8string());` ?

Comment: Also `recursive_directory_iterator` does a lot more than just parse over files in the directory. It parses all intrinsics of all sub-folders and I don't think your code does something of the sort.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the first run might be touching the disk for every file, while the second run might be able to benefit from any disk caching that the disk or OS is doing because the first run warmed up the cache already. Reverse the order in which you run these two, and see if performance changes.

Comment: Yep, first is copy. Second is conversion. I am not sure but `u8string` to `string` might be another conversion or something odd.

Comment: @Thomas I checked it, actually no, added edit in my question.

Comment: I tried it @ home and besides the cache effect (first one who runs takes the penalty) there is indeed a difference in execution speed. It seems that most is caused by the separate 'is_directory' call. In VS2019 this does a GetFileAttributesExW invocation besides a ton of other things.

Comment: @gast128 yes FindFirstFileW and FindNextFileW return the attributes directly which avoids another library call